# How to reference the return value from a function?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function, if-statement

My assignment is to use nested `if` statements to construct a simple translator. Yes, I know that's an awful way to do it, but that's what the assignment says. Here's what I have so far:

```
def translate(word, language):
    '''
    Takes as parameters a string to translate,
    and a second string as the language to translate to.
    Returns the original word, the language, and the word's
    translation in the entered language.
    '''
    en_word = word.lower()
    lang = language.lower()

    #   French
    if lang == "french":
        if en_word == "cat":
            print("chat")            
    if lang == "french":
        if en_word == "dog":
            print("chein")

    #   German      
    if lang == "german":
        if en_word == "cat":
            print("katze")
    if lang == "german":
        if en_word == "dog":
            print("hund")

    #   Spanish      
    if lang == "spanish":
        if en_word == "cat":
            print("gato")
    if lang == "spanish":
        if en_word == "dog":
            print("perro")

translate('cat', 'french')
```

After being called as `translate('cat', 'french')`, for example, the output should be:
`The translation of cat in French is chat`

As it is, my function finds and prints the correct word. I tried using a `return` statement such as

`return en_word, 'French', 'chat'` and a print statement such as

`print('The translation of', translate[0], 'into', translate[1], 'is', translate[2])`

but the error message `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable` popped up. I could put virtually identical `print` statements into each end of the `if` statements in the function, but that seems terribly inelegant.

How can I get the function to return the English word, the language and the translated word to insert into a generic print statement?

Comment: what language is your code?

Comment: Python 3. Sorry, added to the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can restructure your code.

```
def translate(word, language):

    en_word = word.lower()
    lang = language.lower()

    if lang == "french":
        if en_word == "cat":
            return "chat"
        elif en_word == "dog":
            return "chein"

    elif lang == "german":
        if en_word == "cat":
            return "katze"
        elif en_word == "dog":
            return "hund"

    elif lang == "spanish":
        if en_word == "cat":
            return "gato"
        elif en_word == "dog":
            return "perro"

myword = 'cat'
mylanguage = 'french'

res = translate(myword, mylanguage)
print('The translation of {0} in {1} is {2}'.format(myword, mylanguage.title(), res))
```

**Explanation**

- Use `elif` instead of unnecessary repeated `if` statements.
- Have your function `return` a value instead of `print`.
- Use `str.format` to incorporate variables in your `print` statement outside your function.

Comment: That's similar to a construction that I tried, but I wanted to be able to call the function from a console. Thanks, I've accepted yours as an answer.

Comment: @Jim421616, I recommend you use another function, maybe `format_output()`, which runs `translate()` and prints in the format you desire. It's still a good idea to have your logic functions `return` values.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the print function with a return statement?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is specified by your assignment, but in real life, I would use a dictionary of dictionaries as the basis of your ... dictionary and not a bunch of `if` statements:

```
def translate(word,language):
    dictionary = {
      "french": {"cat":"chat",
                 "dog":"chien"},
      "german": {"cat":"katze",
                 "dog":"hund"},
      "spanish": {"cat":"gato",
                  "dog":"perro"}
     }
return(dictionary.get(language).get(word,word))
```

This yields:

```
>>> translate("cat","french")
'chat'
>>> translate("cat","german")
'katze'
>>> translate("dog","german")
'hund'
>>> translate("mouse","spanish")
'mouse'
```

Here it returns the original word if it is not found. You'd want to build in error handling for words or languages that weren't in dictionary,

Comment: I'd normally use a `dict` too, but that's not what the assignment is about!